# Create a function that encodes strings to binary without using SciKit Learn - python 3

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

Creating a function that replaces all strings 't' and 'f' to 1s and 0s...

this is where im at

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        replace_map = {'t':1, 'f': 0,}
        df.columns.map(replace_map) -- not sure what to do here
    return df
```

I have tried psuedocode but unfamiliar with implementing the code itself. Is the `replace` method used here? I was thinking of mapping the values using a dictionary as you may somewhat understand above. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have an example of input ? Why do you use pandas in your case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `.apply` at all. Just use the `DataFrame.replace()` method:

```
def binary_encoding(df):
    return df.replace({"t": 1, "f": 0})

df = pd.DataFrame([['f', 'g', 'h'], ['j', 'k', 't']])
print(df)
   0  1  2
0  f  g  h
1  j  k  t

new_df = binary_encoding(df)
print(new_df)
   0  1  2
0  0  g  h
1  j  k  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply each `map` on one column and save it into the column

```
def binary_encoding(df: pd.DataFrame):
    replace_map = {'t': 1, 'f': 0, }
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].isin(['f', 't']).all(): 
            df[col] = df[col].map(replace_map)
    return df
```

Testing

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['f', 'g', 'h'], ['j', 'k', 't']])
print(df, "\n")
df = binary_encoding(df)
print(df)


   0  1  2
0  f  g  h
1  j  k  t

     0   1    2
0  0.0 NaN  NaN
1  NaN NaN  1.0
```

Comment: This works, however my now current problem is that all other columns containing numerical and string data appear as NaN's. The goal of this function is to locate all columns that just contain 'f' and 't' and encode to binary, while of course leaving all other data as  it were.

Comment: I tried it and there seems to be no changes to the dataframe